# regex for at least three letters anywhere in string

Tags: c#, regex

I currently have the following regex:

```
^(?!.*([A-Za-z0-9])\1{2})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

The entire thing will have the `RegexOption.IgnoreCase` set.  So far it requires:

- at least one letter anywhere
- at least one number anywhere
- not more than two of the same letter or number consecutively (aAa283 is bad, aa83Aa is fine)

I just need to change the "at least one letter" to "at least 3 letters".  I've come up with the following, and it seems to work but I just need to be absolutely sure:

```
^(?!.*([A-Za-z0-9])\1{2})(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]){3})(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

Comment: Your pattern works. `(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]){3})` can also be replaced with a more efficient `(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){3})`. Note that you may shorten the pattern (remove all `a-z` or `A-Z`) if you pass the case insensitive modifier. See [principle of contrast](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast).